# Why is second form displayed outside ot Bootstrap container area?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, paypal, forms

I am using Bootstrap and have two forms within a .container. How is it that the second PayPal form is shown outside the form area?

[image]

HTML

Writer's Tryst - Writers Form

```
    <link type="text/css" href="css/writers.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        body {padding: 0 20px;}
        .limited-offer {
            background-color: white;
            padding:  3px;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <img id="img-writers" src="#" alt="images" />
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form id="form-writers" method="post" class="form-horizontal well pull-left">
                    <h1>Writers</h1>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="title" name="title" autofocus="true" placeholder="Title" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="form-type" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Type of work</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <select class="form-control" required id="form-type" name="form-type"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="genre" class="control-label col-lg-3">Genre</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <select id="genre" name="genre" class="form-control" required></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nbr-pages" class="control-label col-lg-3">Number Pages</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input type="number" id="nbr-pages" name="nbr-pages" class="form-control" required placeholder="Pages" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tips">The objective of a synopsis or query letter is to entice enablers into requesting your manuscript. 
                                    It must be concise and to the point and of course very well written. One page is preferred and no more than 3 pages will be accepted.
                                    <a href="uploads/ron/3997524697.pdf" target="_blank">Sample Query Letter</a>                        
                    </div>
                    <p id="file-warning" class="thumbnail">Your synopsis/query letter must be a PDF file.
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freepdfconvert.com/" target="_blank">Free file conversion to PDF.</a>
                    </p>
                    <div id="upload-container" tabindex="0">
                        <a id="file-upload" class="btn btn-custom-primary btn-file btn-block text-xs-center" role="button">Choose PDF to Upload
                            <br/><div id="filename" class="btn-block" style="color: #fff">No file chosen</div>
                        </a>
                        <input type="file" id="file2upload" style="display: none">
                    </div><br/>
                    <div class="form-group">
    <!--            <button type="submit" id="writers-submit" class="btn btn-custom-success btn-block m-t-8">Submit</button>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="limited-offer">For a limited time, writer submissions will cost <span style="color: #f00; font-weight:bold">$20.00</span> to offset screening and editing costs and to promote quality synopsises and query letters. We reserve the right to change this policy without notice.</div>

    <!--                <form id="form-paypal" name="form-paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit()">-->
                    <input id="userid" name="userid" type="hidden" />
                    <input id="filesize-limit" name="filesize-limit" type="hidden" value="150000" /> 
                </form>
            </div> <!-- col-md-12 -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form id="form-paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="8MEQLAJ8WKG2L">
                    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                    <img alt="paypal" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
            </div> <!-- col-md-12 -->
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap each form in a div with class col-xx-x; something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-x>
      # your first form here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-x>
      # your second form here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

note that the `x` in `col-md-x` must be replaced by an integer from 1 to 12 considering how much space yp want to give to each column.

Also, remove the `<div>` that you use to wrap Paypal form and replace it with the `<div class="col-md-x>` as showed above.

Check [bootstrap grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) for more info.

Comment: We're getting closer. I reposted with the changes you suggested. Notice the PayPal form lies beneath the wall and is too far right.

Comment: if you want the PayPal form to be in the grey area you should apply the styling to the wrapper of both columns, which in this case is row. Add another class to the row-div and style it. For the alignment, I'm not sure, but you could try to remove the pull-left class from the first form. If you have a live example you can link I might check :)